# remove readonly in inpput of form with tree Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree

How do I fix this error , using tree in jquery . I can get the specific button using ( form> .button ) used his class and only change the button with the "this" . however I can not change the attributes only of inputs in the form parent, I caught up with the $ (this ) .closest ( 'form' ) . attr ( 'id' ).

```
<form name='bolovo' id='bolovo' method="post">

 <input type='text' name='nome' readonly id='nome' value='nome' </input>
<input type='button' readonly name='editarBotao' id='edit' class='button' value='Edit'/>
    </form>

         <br><br>
             <form name='queijo' id='queijo' method="post">

 <input type='text' name='nome1' id='nome1' readonly value='nome1' </input>
     <input type='button' readonly name='editarBotao' id='edit' class='button' value='Edit'/>
                 </form>

<script>
$("form > .button").click(function(){

        if (this.value == 'Edit') {
        this.value = 'Save';
       var formid = ( $(this).closest('form').attr('id') );
    alert (formid);
      $(this).closest('form').appendChild(input).removeAttr('readonly');
        //$('form > input').removeAttr('readonly');


        }else{
            this.value = 'Save';
            $('form > input').attr('readonly', true);
            var formid = ( $(this).closest('form').attr('id') );
            alert (formid);
        };
});
</script>
```

Comment: There are many errors inside your code, for example closing input tags, id's which are not unique. In the JS fragment I find the line: $(this).closest('form').appendChild(input).removeAttr('readonly'); - what is the purpose of that? there is no variable input, and do you really want top append or just update the attribute?

Comment: just update the attribute in the form specific

Comment: $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='text']").removeAttr('readonly');